# use external liste error :Oracle database TNS The value's length for key 'data source' exceeds it's limit of '128'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, bcs, external-content-type, external-list, bdc-model

I have created xml model for external list using bcs
this is the code example for my BDCM model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Model xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog
 BDCMetadata.xsd" Name="Portail_Oracle">
  <LobSystems>
    <LobSystem Type="Database" Name="Portail_Oracle">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="WildcardCharacter" Type="System.String">%</Property>
      </Properties>
      <LobSystemInstances>
        <LobSystemInstance Name="Portail_Oracle">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="ShowInSearchUI" Type="System.String"></Property>
            <Property Name="DatabaseAccessProvider" Type="System.String">Oracle</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Data Source" Type="System.String">(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = @IP)(PORT = 1521))(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = RAP)(FAILOVER_MODE =(TYPE = SELECT)(METHOD = BASIC)(RETRIES = 180)(DELAY = 5))))</Property>
            <Property Name="AuthenticationMode" Type="System.String">PassThrough</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Integrated Security" Type="System.String"></Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection User ID" Type="System.String">RH</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Password" Type="System.String">RH</Property>


          </Properties>
        </LobSystemInstance>
      </LobSystemInstances>
      <Entities>
        <Entity Name="ABC" Namespace="Oracle" Version="1.0.0.0">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="OriginalName" Type="System.String">"RH"."Portail"</Property>
            <Property Name="EntitySetName" Type="System.String">"RH"."Portail"</Property>
          </Properties>
          <Identifiers>
            <Identifier Name="MAT" TypeName="System.Int64" />
          </Identifiers>
          <Methods>
            <Method Name="GetAll_P">
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="RdbCommandType" Type="System.Data.CommandType, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">Text</Property>
                <Property Name="RdbCommandText" Type="System.String">select MAT, BN, ....  from Portail</Property>
              </Properties>
              <Parameters>
                <Parameter Name="GetAll_P_returned" Direction="Return">
                  <TypeDescriptor Name="comptes_list" TypeName="System.Data.IDataReader, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" IsCollection="true">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="comptes" TypeName="System.Data.IDataRecord, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                        <TypeDescriptors>
                        <TypeDescriptor Name="MAT" TypeName="System.Int64">
                            <Interpretation>
                               <ConvertType LOBType="System.Int64" BDCType="System.String" />
                            </Interpretation>
                          </TypeDescriptor>                     
                          <TypeDescriptor Name="BN" TypeName="System.Int64">
                            <Interpretation>
                               <ConvertType LOBType="System.Int64" BDCType="System.String" />
                            </Interpretation>
                          </TypeDescriptor>

                          ...
```

I following this model https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff512794(v=office.14).aspx
and It succefylly create the external content type
when I create the external list atteched to the external content type and i try to open the list

I got the error

> Sorry ... we could not recover the data. If the problem persists,
>   contact the web server administrator

.
at sharepoint log :

> Oracle database TNS The value's length for key 'data source' exceeds
>   it's limit of '128'

In fact i add all the autorisation
any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer: [BCS UserProfile Sync to Oracle not working after upgrade from Oracle 10 to Oracle 11](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165153/bcs-userprofile-sync-to-oracle-not-working-after-upgrade-from-oracle-10-to-oracl)

You have to take care for type of field.